# Remove duplicate string in java

Tags: java, android

I have two different string, let's say:

```
s1 = "hello"
s2 = "helloworlde1"
```

I want to get result as `worlde1`.

Can anybody suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: I think this question is mainly due to the OP not knowing where to start? @SachinGupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 s2=s2.replace(s1,"");
```

this will remove s1 from s2

Answer (score 0):

Hope below small example will help you.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        String s1="hello";
        String s2="helloworlde1";
        s2=s2.replace(s1, "");
        System.out.println(s2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the duplicate string is always going to be in front of the other string e.g

```
s2="helloworlde1"
```

then you can use Java "substring" like this

```
string output = s2.substring(s1.length())
```

otherwise you need some other logic to locate where the duplicated string is before using the substring method